# System.InvalidCastException when deserializing file with a memorystream assembly instance of an exe app

Tags: c#, serialization, memorystream

I'm currently working on an application which will creates/opens files using binary serialization.
In order to protect my work, I was thinking of encrypting my exe file (using a key stored in a hidden secured access location), and using an execution wrapper that decrypts the file and loads the app directly in memory.

The problem I have is that I can't open the serialized files saved using the unencrypted .exe with an instance of decrypted app loaded directly in memory using my execution wrapper... It returns a System.InvalidCastException because of Context difference.

In order to make it more clear, here are the steps I performed :

1. Developping the Main C# application and generating .exe file
2. Developping a C# code in order to encrypt the main application .exe for deployment
3. Developping an C# execution wrapper which decrypts the file, gets the Main app assembly from the decoded byte array, and invokes "Main" method, all that performed without intermediate file in order to keep unprotected application "hidden"

So at that point, I can execute my Main App starting with an encrypted file, without any access to my original unencrypted program.
But when I want to deserialize a file generated with a local version of my original .exe, here is the message I get :

*System.InvalidCastException : 
'[A] can't be converted to [B].
A type coming from ', Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in 'Default' context at location ', Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in 'LoadNeither' context of a byte array.*

Would there be any way to skip context during deserialization, in order to ensure backward compatibility with files saved using uncrypted versions of my app ?

Thank you very much for your help and time.

Regards

Comment: have you considered embedding the exe( that you want to encrypt) within another C# lets call WrapperApp. Then you can extract this exe from wrapper app on demand and perform the tasks you want. then you can instruct the wrapper app to delete this extracted exe, does this work for you ?

Comment: You must use the same version of the class when doing a binary serialization and then deserialization.  If you change properties in the class between serialize and deserialize it will not work.  Also make sure you set the Position of the memory stream after loading to zero before reading from the memory stream.

Comment: Hi, first of all, thank you very much for your time ! Clint, in order to prevent any "intruder" from copying the exe, one of my goals issu to prevent any temp storage of an unencrypted exe

Comment: jdweng, the version of the class is exactly the same, as I serialized a file with the unenecrypted exe, and then I just encrypted/unencrypted the exact same exe in my AppWrapper and launched the app directly in RAM. And when I deserialize with the "in-RAM" instance I get the Exception. So the exe preforming serialization and deserialization is exactly the same. It is just the way I launch it which is different.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way out of this situation.

I created a DLL containing my serialized /deserialized object. This way may not protect the content of the DLL, but at least it protects the "brain" of the app, which is contained in the encrypted .exe.

Regards